# Sending packets between interfaces using ping

Tags: networking, ping, p2p

I would like to send packets from one interface to another one by using ping. I created two interfaces in Ubuntu, let's say interface-A and interface-B. Interface-A and interface-B are p2p connected to each other using WifiDirect. I enter interactive mode in interface-A and try sending packets to interface-B using command "ping 172.16.25.125" (172.16.25.125 is the Inet address of interface-B. I can see that when I type "ifconfig"). This command gives me response of "PONG". First of all, what does PONG mean? Then, how can I send packets A-->B using ping?

Comment: Ping often stands for `ping-pong`, `send-receive or `echo-request -echo-reply`

Comment: You can see from this example http://imgur.com/a/Q2HrW how it works.  I was pinging my router f.e.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, I can't see anything on the link that you shared.

Comment: Whoops, seems image wasn't uploaded properly.
Try this:
http://imgur.com/a/OUmQM

Answer (score 0):

PING is a type of packet, so you can't send packets using ping.

Ping is an "echo request" and pong is an "echo response".

These packets are used to check if the other side is reachable and responding.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understand what you are saying, but when I type "ping 172.16.25.126" without getting into interactive mode, I get the response of "64 bytes from 172.16.25.126: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms" until I stop the process with control+C. In this case, what is the difference between having a "PONG" response and "64 bytes from 172.16.25.126: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.018 ms"?

Comment: In fact, I've just found out that no matter I type after ping command, such as "ping 3241234" the terminal always responds with "PONG". I wonder whether PONG response really means the destination is reachable. 3241234 is not even an IP address.

Comment: I am sure what is PONG used for.  Network Layer in the OSI model does not use only Internet Protocol (IP), it also uses Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP). You can see in terminal output "icmp_seq=1" that your were communicating with the other host using ICMP which checks up is the other host "alive" and reachable for you.

Comment: I`m not sure why you get PONG response for invalid ping request.

Answer (score 0):

PONG verifies that the ping was successful and that you are indeed sending packets and that they are being received. I apologize if this shows up in the low quality answer queue due to length but sometimes little is required as in this case.

Source:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts

Comment: Thank you! (I am at the beginner level, by the way.) You're saying that when I use ping, packets are being sent and they are received. As far as I know, the usage is "ping [destination specification using IP address]",but I can't figure out what the source is. When I type ifconfig I see number of interfaces. I use one computer and there are two antennas attached to the computer each having 2 interfaces. Then, I type "ping 172.16.25.125", which corresponds to the IP addresses of one of the interfaces. It seems to be sending packets fine. In this case, what is my source? Please help me with that

Comment: I just found for setting the source. I use "-I". Now, my problem is that the destination seems to be unreachable. interface-A and interface-B are connected to each other through p2p. In interactive mode of interface-A and checked the connection using "ping [int-B address]", which in return I got "PONG". This means int-B is reachable from int-A, doesn't it? However, out of the interactive mode, in order to send packets int-A-->int-B, when I use the command "ping -I int-A 172.16.25.126" I got the response of "From 172.16.25.125 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable". Simply why?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Do you have a new question regarding how to tell your network interfaces apart? by p2p do you mean UDP? Perhaps this is the information you are looking for: https://wiki.itadmins.net/network/tcp_udp_ping